# Formik Field not displaying entered value

Tags: reactjs, formik, formik-material-ui

https://codesandbox.io/s/friendly-bohr-mjyhc

This is the code snippet of my form, I have created a field and I want to change its value onChange. I don't see the value changing on the screen and when I console log the event.target.value I only see the current letter being replaced from the previous letter (if I type AB, the console log values show A and then it replaces to B)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Formik` library itself provides various method to handle the complexity.

In your code rather than adding a custom handle Change you can directly use `handleChange` method.

Simply replace -

`onChange={customChange}`

with

`onChange={handleChange}`

to make this work.

FYI - I also printed `values` so that you can see the `formik` bag of values.

Here is the working code -
[Code Sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/nostalgic-kare-k1556?file=/src/App.js:549-561)

**EDIT 1 -**

If you want to update the value from a custom handler then you can use `setFieldValue` for setting the field value.

Working Code - [CodeSandBox 1](https://codesandbox.io/s/nostalgic-kare-k1556?file=/src/App.js)

Comment: Thanks Swapnesh, I was struggling to use formik's handlechange. I see the value getting printed in your codesandbox, but if you notice the onChange functioned is not triggered (not printing the console that you wrote)

Comment: @PushpendraYadav: I have updated my answer, though I will suggest you to firstly read the docs and run examples, so that you will realise various conditions in which formik forms would be helpful.

Comment: Swapnesh, It did help, thanks a lot. Yes, I am going through its documentation as well though I find the docs a bit scattered.